# How to set default option in select component with null-value in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, html-select, v-model

There is a select with v-model. Initially, there is null. In option, I also specify null for the default value - everything works, the default value is substituted.
But as soon as I put this select into a separate component, for some reason it stops working with null, the default option is not substituted.
Link to documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

A call in the parent component:

Parent.vue

```
<filter-trashed-select v-model="filters.trashed.fieldValue"/>
```

FilterTrashedSelect.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="reference__filter-select-wrapper">
        <select class="form-select" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
            <option :value="null">{{ $t('Only active') }}</option>
            <option value="only">{{ $t('Only hidden') }}</option>
            <option value="with">{{ $t('All') }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "FilterTrashedSelect",
    props: ['modelValue'],
    emits: ['update:modelValue']
}
</script>
```

1. I tried substituting the null value explicitly

```
<template>
    <div class="reference__filter-select-wrapper">
        <select class="form-select" :value="null" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
            <option :value="null">{{ $t('Only active') }}</option>
            <option value="only">{{ $t('Only hidden') }}</option>
            <option value="with">{{ $t('All') }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "FilterTrashedSelect",
    props: ['modelValue'],
    emits: ['update:modelValue']
}
</script>
```

2. I tried using the extended version of v-model when calling

Parent.vue

```
<filter-trashed-select :modelValue="filters.trashed.fieldValue"
  @update:modelValue="newValue => filters.trashed.fieldValue= newValue"/>
```

3. But if you take this select out of the component, and use it explicitly in Parent.vue, then everything works

Simplified the example with the problem on [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNq1U9tOwzAM/RUrQhpIW6vxWAoC8QlIvFAeSutBUZtEiVuQpv47dtKVXcTeeEqcc3zs+LJVD9YmQ48qU7mvXGMJPFJv7wrddNY4gsePpq1h40wHiyQNljgsZsIWHG5gnCgRKnRltCcg9LSGW2Fc6r5tr/aB6wlY82uexugclw3CzrYlIVsAed0M4QJTLpXhwBo1wU5TsLwK4LDqTI3tbaFC7EKlUSTdqZyTk0z+1Lo+q/WELVZHGfn4dpLS5JIbS43RkA1l2yPD4suoHHkawSPqjiki6wMOFzBEO8hQ7lLbuZ5qqWLXVl1pk09vNDd+G2gT4AuVQXiRN+6m2IX6ILI+S1O/qaT7nz4x7j3lW+J6TU2HCfpu9ebMl0fHwoVa7mlwbm5At3Koa3TozmkeUU90RXYs9MhfmYdRpvdwZmIxYgpzfUMbnsWIMgD3jbY9MXSBXUOXi97WLJH9EhdLuMCBhyOh0r0jJUHrKvr/cx/3+sbGvB/4Hdauxk3Zt7x+4mWd4VLCy+EfX0MP5GcRO/ldpIw3e/unxh9GnmAF).

Solved.
In the component, you need to use the v-model. But you can't use it on a property, to do this, create a variable in data.

```
<template>
  <select v-model="test" @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
    <option :value="null">null</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["modelValue"],
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  data() {
    return {
      test: this.modelValue
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: added a solution with v-model

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to choose something else as `null` for the default value.
Null is not a value and should not be treated as value. Null is rather absence of value.

If you use null as value in the select option, then Vue use the Option's Text as value. Check the playground below, how the `showValue()` prints 'Only active' if you chose the first option.

It's interesting, that `:value="modelValue"` and `v-model="modelValue"` behaves differently. Check how the both selects react of the selecting the first option. I have no explanation for this, at this point.

The best solution is to use some `default` value for your prop and validate it to set the default value.

```
<option value="active">Only active</option>
```

and

```
props: {
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: 'active',
    validator: function (value) {
        return ['active', 'only', 'with'].includes(value)
    }
  }
}
```

The `null` is still bad to pass, since it even does not causes the validation to occur. Here iI have also no idea why it is so.
It's better to use `undefined` instead of `null`, since `undefined` causes the validation to occur.

Check the following [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) for details.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = {
 setup() { 
  const modelValue = ref(null)
  const showValue = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    modelValue.value = value
  }
  return  { 
    modelValue, 
    showValue 
   } 
 }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  modelValue: {{modelValue}}<br/>
  modelValue == null: {{modelValue == null}}<br/>
  <hr/>
  Select bound with <b>v-model</b> <select class="form-select" v-model="modelValue" @input="showValue($event.target.value)">
      <option :value="null">Only active</option>
      <option value="only">Only hidden</option>
      <option value="with">All</option>
  </select><br/>
 Select bound with <b>:value</b> <select class="form-select" :value="modelValue" @input="showValue($event.target.value)">
      <option :value="null">Only active</option>
      <option value="only">Only hidden</option>
      <option value="with">All</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changed null to an empty string in my project. I will take note of this platform (sfc.vuejs.org), as well as the validation method.
Also simplified the example with the problem.

Comment: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)